# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen' (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I am writing a program for my school, and I'm hosting the daily SBWATs (Students Will Be Able To) for each teacher in text files.  Here is my code, SchoolNet.py

```
import Tkinter
import urllib
print urllib.__file__

def showsbwat(teacher):
    sbwat = urllib.openurl("192.168.1.203/" + teacher + ".txt")
    print sbwat

def showshecdule():
    mainwindow.withdraw()
    schedulewindow.deiconify()
    firstperiodbutton = Tkinter.Button(schedulewindow, text = periodlist[0], command = lambda: showsbwat(periodlist[0]))
    firstperiodbutton.pack()
    global sbwatlabel
    sbwatlabel = Tkinter.Label(schedulewindow, text = "")
    sbwatlabel.pack()

def login():
    try:
        schedulefile = open(usernamevar.get() + ".txt", "r")
        global periodlist
        periodlist = schedulefile.readlines()
        print periodlist
        mainwindow.deiconify()
        loginwindow.withdraw()
    except:
        usernamevar.set("Invalid ID")

loginwindow = Tkinter.Tk()
loginwindow.wm_title('Login to SchoolNet')

mainwindow = Tkinter.Tk()
mainwindow.wm_title('SchoolNet')

schedulewindow = Tkinter.Tk()
schedulewindow.wm_title('SchoolNet Schedule')

mainwindow.withdraw()
schedulewindow.withdraw()
loginwindow.deiconify()

schedulebut = Tkinter.Button(mainwindow, text = 'Schedule', command=showshecdule)
schedulebut.pack()

usernamevar = Tkinter.StringVar()
usernameentry = Tkinter.Entry(loginwindow, textvariable=usernamevar)
usernameentry.pack()

loginbut = Tkinter.Button(loginwindow, text="Login", command=login)
loginbut.pack()

Tkinter.mainloop()
```

But, when I run it, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "SchoolNet.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    firstperiodbutton = Tkinter.Button(schedulewindow, text = periodlist[0], com
mand = lambda: showsbwat(periodlist[0]))
  File "SchoolNet.py", line 6, in showsbwat
    sbwat = urllib.openurl("192.168.1.203/" + teacher + ".txt")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openurl'
```

I have tried this with urllib and urllib2, but I get the same error.  None of the other files in the directory are named the same of any python modules.  What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: change it to `urllib.urlopen()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `urlopen` not `openurl`:

```
 urllib.urlopen()
```

Answer (score 1):

from urllib.request import urlopen

URL = "www.webpage-address"

page= urlopen(URL)

text = page.read()